# pyspark how to fit a GLM using log as link function with Sum of weights as zero

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, glm

Im trying to experiment on the different GLM link function for my regression model. When I tried to use link function of log or inverse I am getting this error below:

Is there a way to specify a fit to a glm with Sum of weights as zero using gamma or gaussian?

```
An error occurred while calling o1677.fit.
: java.lang.AssertionError: assertion failed: Sum of weights cannot be zero.
    at scala.Predef$.assert(Predef.scala:170)
    at org.apache.spark.ml.optim.WeightedLeastSquares$Aggregator.validate(WeightedLeastSquares.scala:418)
    at org.apache.spark.ml.optim.WeightedLeastSquares.fit(WeightedLeastSquares.scala:101)
    at org.apache.spark.ml.optim.IterativelyReweightedLeastSquares.fit(IterativelyReweightedLeastSquares.scala:86)
```

Here is my code

```
def fit_GLM_Log(training,testing):
    from pyspark.ml.regression import GeneralizedLinearRegression
    training.cache()
    glr = GeneralizedLinearRegression(featuresCol = 'features',labelCol = 'STOP_START_TIME',\
                                      family="gaussian", link="log"\
                                      ,maxIter=10, regParam=0.3)

    glr_model = glr.fit(training)
    testing.cache()

    # Print the coefficients and intercept for generalized linear regression model
    print("Coefficients: " + str(glr_model.coefficients))
    print("Intercept: " + str(glr_model.intercept))

    # Summarize the model over the training set and print out some metrics
    summary = glr_model.summary
    print("Coefficient Standard Errors: " + str(summary.coefficientStandardErrors))
    print("T Values: " + str(summary.tValues))
    print("P Values: " + str(summary.pValues))
    print("Dispersion: " + str(summary.dispersion))
    print("Null Deviance: " + str(summary.nullDeviance))
    print("Residual Degree Of Freedom Null: " + str(summary.residualDegreeOfFreedomNull))
    print("Deviance: " + str(summary.deviance))
    print("Residual Degree Of Freedom: " + str(summary.residualDegreeOfFreedom))
    print("AIC: " + str(summary.aic))
    print("Deviance Residuals: ")
    summary.residuals().show()

    prediction_result = glr_model.transform(testing)

    return prediction_result
```

I am using PySpark and running Spark 2.2 at this time.
I have searched the apache sites and I did not see any suggestions on how to resolve this issue

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error and this is how I resolved it. Some of the observations in my data had missing values in either dependent variable, independent variables or weight. I removed these observation and it worked. SAS seems to drop these observations during the fit, but GeneralizedLinearRegression doesn't seem to check the data before using it. Turned out, it had nothing to do with weights. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same error without any null values in my data.  I had to scale my dependent variable (dividing by 1000, in my case).  Apparently, the solver crashes if the weight matrix gets too small because part of the algorithm is to multiply by the inverse of the weight matrix, which amounts to dividing by zero.

Answer (score 0):

This has also happened to me when I used apparently and unsuitable GLM (with family=Gamma and link=log) for my data. The data probably had too long tail, because cutting the tail (treating those values as outliers) helped. Also, changing the GLM to family=gaussian and link=log helped. So try investigating your data and try different types of GLM.